# In command `java`, does `-cp` override `$CLASSPATH`, or prefix it?

Tags: java

When running a .class program with command `java`, if a dependency is not found in `-cp`, will it be searched for in environment variable `$CLASSPATH`? In otherwords, does `-cp` override `$CLASSPATH`, or prefix  it?

I saw an example:

```
java -cp "${CLASSPATH}:${SCALA_HOME}/lib/scala-library.jar:target/scala-2.10/basic_2.10-1.0.jar" foo.bar.baz.Main
```

What is the purpose of adding `${CLASSPATH}` to `-cp`?

Thanks.

Comment: In that specific example it's to be able to *add* Scala jars to the classpath already defined by `$CLASSPATH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `CLASSPATH` along with `-cp` you need to add it in the `-cp`. `-cp` does not imply the use of the env variable `CLASSPATH`. The possible scenarios are:

1. CLASSPATH not set, no use of `-cp`: the default classpath is used.
2. CLASSPATH set, no use of `-cp`: the directories in CLASSPATH are used.
3. `-cp` is set: the directories passed via the option are used.

Answer (score 0):

> In command `java`, does `-cp` override `$CLASSPATH`, or prefix it?

One word answer is: **None**

In the following command, `-cp` or `-classpath` means you are instructing `java` to look for `foo.bar.baz.Main` in the paths mentioned within double quotes

```
java -cp "${CLASSPATH}:${SCALA_HOME}/lib/scala-library.jar:target/scala-2.10/basic_2.10-1.0.jar" foo.bar.baz.Main
```

which are

1. The path set in the `CLASSPATH` environment variable.
2. `<<The path set in the`SCALA_HOME`environment variable>>/lib/scala-library.jar:target/scala-2.10/basic_2.10-1.0.jar`.